# simple conditional probability question involving accidents

Tags: probability

in a town we have 90% red bicycles and 10% blue bicycles. A accident occurs - a witness says she is 90% sure the accident was caused by the red bicycle. What is the probability that the bicycle causing the accident is red?

This is a quesiton on conditional probability - we need to find $P(R | W)$ where $W$ is the witnesses statement. I am just not sure on how to use: "a witness says she is 90% sure the accident was caused by the red bicycle" in calculations

just to add: I have received an answer of 0.9 which seems incorrect

Comment: Your exercise is most likely intended to test your knowledge of the definition of conditional probability, and perhaps of Bayes formula.  Are there exercises already worked for you which are similar?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the tree diagram:

[image: prob-tree]

Let $R=\{\text{Car is red}\}$. Then $P(R)=0.9$.

Let $B=\{\text{Car is blue}\}$. Then $P(B)=0.1$.

Let $W=\{\text{Onlooker sees the car the colour of the branch it emanates from}\}$, and $W^c$ is the complement of this event. Then

$$P(W|R)=0.9\quad\text{and}\quad P(W|B)=0.1$$
Now by [Baye's Theorem on conditional probability:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

$$P(R|W)=\frac{P(W|R)P(R)}{P(W|R)P(R)+P(W|B)P(B)}$$
giving
$$P(R|W)=\frac{0.9\times 0.9}{0.9\times 0.9+0.1\times0.1}=\frac{0.81}{0.81+0.01}=\frac{81}{82}\approx0.9878$$

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

R ~ the bicycle in a town is red .............. $P(R) = 0.9$

B ~ the bicycle in a town is blue ........... $P(B) = 0.1$

$W_t$ ~ the witness has the right ............... $P(W_t) = 0.9$

$W_f$ ~ the witness was wrong ................. $P(W_f)=0.1$

a) Probability - a bicycle accident was the red:

$\quad P_R=P(R)\cdot P(W_t) + P(B)\cdot P(W_f)=0.9\cdot 0.9 + 0.1 \cdot 0.1 = 0.82$

b) Probability - a bicycle accident was the blue:

$\quad P_B=P(B)\cdot P(W_t) + P(R)\cdot P(W_f)=0.1\cdot 0.9 + 0.9 \cdot 0.1 = 0.18$